# What natural processes are most sensitive to exact value of fine-structure constant?

Tags: standard-model, quantum-electrodynamics, physical-constants

My intuition (game theory PhD here, no serious background in physics) suggests that of all naturally observable processes protein folding should have the strongest dependence on exact value of $\alpha$ due to its enormous complexity working to amplify slightest differences in wave function shapes on its every step. What I mean here is that we should be able to imagine an aternative world with $\alpha' = \alpha + \Delta \alpha$, where $\Delta \alpha$ is small enough to have no discernible effect on inorganic chemistry, but big enough to make all proteins fold into completely different tertiary structures.

If my intuition is correct, is it possible that value of fine-structure constant has no other meaning then pinpointing exact version of our evolutionary biology out of numerous viable variations? As in: "For my universe $\frac{1}{\alpha} \simeq 137.035999084$ simply because I look into mirror and see hemoglobin-breathing creature. Somewhere on other multiverse plane creepy lovecraftian abomination with wildly different biochemistry may be wondering, why $\frac{1}{\alpha'} \simeq 136,964000916$ (difference not to scale)."

Comment: Guys, seriously - 50 views and not even one downvote? Is this question really so nonsensical? If I'm shadowbanned by SCP Foundation trying to suppress dangerous ideas - please keep in mind that I'm currently open for employment proposals and have much wilder stuff in my sleeve ;-)